# I can't see deployed field after deployment via change sets (but I can see that field in setup)

Tags: soql, deployment, custom-field, change-set, deployment-error

I deployed my code through change sets from full copy sandbox to production: I included my new custom field and I can see that field on Contact from Setup on Production:
[image]

But despite adding them at page layouts, I still can't see them on Contact records on Production.

I can't access a field also from SOQL on Production:
[image]

What can be the reason of that error here? I checked also on Classic - I also don't see that field on a record. I did deployment about 20 minutes ago

Comment: Most likely permissions not granted to access the field for the user you are logged in as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you deploy the field through change set its field level security is not configured automatically unless you add the profile to the change set.

Checkout the official [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.changesets_perm_sets_profiles.htm&type=5) outlining the behavior.

Make sure you edit the field level security for the field and configure it to be read only or edit as needed.